# Difference between printing pointer address and ampersand address

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers, memory-address

```
int firstInt =10;
int *pointerFirstInt = &firstInt;


printf("The address of firstInt is: %u", &firstInt);
printf("\n");
printf("The address of firstInt is: %p", pointerFirstInt);
printf("\n");
```

The above code returns the following:

```
The address of firstInt is: 1606416332
The address of firstInt is: 0x7fff5fbff7cc
```

I know that `0x7fff5fbff7cc` is in hexadecimal, but when i attempt to convert that number to decimal it does not equal `1606416332`. Why is this? Shouldn't both return the same memory address?

Comment: `%u` is `unsigned int` format, likely 32 bits in length. Your pointer is very obviously bigger than 32 bits... You should use the `%p` format in both calls to printf().

Comment: `0x7fff5fbff7cc - 1606416332 == 0x7fff5fbff7cc - 0x5fbff7cc == 0x7fff00000000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your hexadecimal address-

```
The address of firstInt is: 0x7fff5fbff7cc
```

The size of the address is 6 bytes long. But Size of `unsignedint` is 4 bytes. When you trying to print the address using `%u`, It will cause undefined behaviour.

So always print the address using `%p`.

Comment: so, without using a pointer, this `printf("The address of firstInt is: %p", &firstInt);` is correct?

Comment: @JustinO'Brien yeah! that's correct!. but from your question if you want print using `%lu` and convert it to hexadecimal and see.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is lies here:

#### C11: 7.21.6:

> If a conversion specification is invalid, **the behavior is undefined**.<sup>288)</sup> If any argument is
> not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is
> undefined.

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you are working on an 64bit machine. so your pointer is 64bit long

both (`&firstInt` and `pointerFirstInt`) are exactly same. but are displayed differently.
`"%p"` knows that pointers are 64bit and displays them in hexadecimal. `"%u"` shows decimal number and assumes 32bit. so only a part is shown.

if you convert `1606416332` to hexadecimal it looks like: `0x5FBFF7CC`. you see that this is the lower half of the 64bit address.

edit:
further explanations:

since printf is a var-arg function all the parametes you give to it were put on the stack. since you put 8 byte on it in both cases. since Pcs using little endian the lower bytes are put on it first.
the printf function parses the string and comes to an `%[DatatypeSpecifier]` point and reads as many bytes from stack as the datatype that is refered by DatatypeSpecifier requires. so in case of `"%u"` it only reads 4 bytes and ignores the other bytes. Since you wrote `"%u"` and not `"%x"` it displays the value in decimal and not in hexadecimal form.